# a way to add an event on next button in a jface wizard?

Tags: jface, wizard

I am developing a jface wizard , and I need to do some treatement when I click on the next Button on the wizardPage , not on the finish button on the wizard.
Is there an event to use to do so ? My wizard page extends WizardPage.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The way to go about this is in your Page that extends WizardPage in the default Constructor set a unique name for that page. Then in the Wizard class override this method:

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage(IWizardPage page) {
    return super.getNextPage(page); 

}
```

then based on the page.getName() you can see if its the page you want to do processing on when the user clicks next. You can cast it to your specific wizard page and here you have control to either add error message, setPageComplete to false or do anything you need to. That is the best approach. If you override getNextPage() on the wizard page itself it will get called before the page is shown and not a good approach.

Comment: `getNextPage()` is also called from other places such as wizard's 'updateButtons()' so this might be worth considering when overriding this method. There is also a `setVisible(boolean)` method that can be considered if something needs to be done when a page hides.